# How to split a String in Dart, Flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart, backend

I am getting a String balance from the backend, and it is something like this 430000.
I would like to have an output like this 430,000.
How do I go about it?

```
Row(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 12,
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                "₦ ${user.availableBalance.toStringAsFixed(0)} ",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 21.sp,
                                ),
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use `Regex` so define this on the top

```
 class _HomeTabState extends State<HomeTab>  {

  //Regex
  RegExp reg = RegExp(r'(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))'); //immport dar:core
  RegExp regex = RegExp(r'([.]*0)(?!.*\d)');
String Function(Match) mathFunc = (Match match) => '${match[1]},'; //match
...
//In your build
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
Row(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 12,
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                "₦ ${double.parse(user.availableBalance.toString()).toStringAsFixed(0)} " .replaceAllMapped(
                                                    reg, mathFunc),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 21.sp,
                                ),
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
...
}

}
```

Then to use it just turn your balance into a double then to String in order to access the `toStringAsFixed(0)` like this

```
"${double.parse(balance.toString()).toStringAsFixed(0)}".replaceAllMapped(reg, mathFunc),
```

so for 430 -> would be 430 and 4300 -> would be 4,300 and 43000 -> would be 43,000

Comment: This appears like the solution, but I don't really understand how to use it.

Comment: Please add your code so that you can be helped!

Comment: I have attached my code..

Comment: So I have update the code: So this is how it works, the RegExp just removes decimals and matches to the other defined `mathFunc`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `intl` package https://pub.dev/packages/intl
Example usage:

```
var f = NumberFormat("#,###.##");
print(f.format(123456789.4567));
```

This will result in the following output:

```
123,456,789.46
```

Note that `,` in the pattern specifies the grouping separator and `###` specifies the group size to be 3. `.##`specifies rounding on two decimal points.

---

Check for additional documentation:  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat-class.html