# Why am i getting invalid double exception

Tags: flutter, html-parsing

I have searched for similar threads here on stack overflow.But I couldnt  find a solution.Tried to debug my app and realized that my app crashes here

```
 var price = double.parse(prices[i].replaceAll(",", "."));
```

I have been working for hours  on this problem.

```
   var content = parser.parse(doc);
var allBooks =
    content.querySelectorAll("div.facet__products div.prd-main-wrapper");
var prices = allBooks
    .map((e) => e.getElementsByClassName("prd-price")[0].text.trim())
    .toList();
 
  for (int i = 0; i < allBooks.length; i++) {

      var price =double.parse(prices[i].replaceAll(",", "."));
      var name = names[i].toString();
      var author = authors[i].toString();
      var img = imgs[i].toString();
      BookModel model = BookModel(name, author, img, price, "D.R");
      controller.books.add(model);
      print(allBooks);
    }
```

Comment: If your prices have more than one "," that means replacing them with "." makes that number have multiple decimal points which is not a valid double (as an example 72,00,00 will be converted to 72.00.00 which is not a valid double). A double value should only have one decimal. I would suggest you to replace the first "," with "." and rest of the commas with an empty string like this "". Hope that helps :)

Comment: Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72760623/how-to-split-a-string-in-dart-flutter

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. My price value has one ","

Comment: Exactly what is the string that you're trying to parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change var price to double price

```
double price = double.parse(prices[i].toString().replaceAll(",", "")) ?? 0.0;
```

Edit

```
double? price = double.tryParse(prices[i].toString().replaceAll(",", ""));
```

Comment: thanks for replying. Now ,I get this warning  "  Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'double' which excludes null." And the problem persists

Comment: This just silently replaces the value with `0.0` if it can't be parsed.  It's not clear if that's what the OP wants (e.g., maybe they have a string `'1,234,567.89'` and want to actually parse it), and not explaining that is dangerous to people who just blindly copy and paste code.

Comment: I have removed the . And made it replace only , with emptry string.  that should give proper results for numbers like what you have mentioned